# Small Carvings and statues in pillars in temples

Tags: scripture, temple

If we observe in ancient temples there are lot of carvings and statues comprising animals, flowers, hanuman, vinayaga, brahmahathi etc in pillars. Further ancient man and woman in different poses can also be found in statue form. Any scriptural evidence from hindu mythology-- why these mixed carvings and statues are put on the pillars?

Comment: +1 for good question .I think the reasons might be  1)  decoration purpose 2) max. utilisation of avaliable space , as there are lots of gods and stories.etc. I dont think the answer is written somewhere , but still will try to find one.